# I want to change between geometry nodes via script instead of the dropdown menu in the properties section

Tags: scripting, geometry-nodes

i added a Geometry Node Modifier via script to a grid i have, now i want to change this modifier from the default empty geo node to a geo modifier i already finished, which sits on an object in the same scene. Basically i want to change the geo modifier that gets put on top of the grid via the script and not via the dropdown in the properties window.
I am relatively new to scripting and cant find anything related to that by googling.
I hope someone can help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

[Geometry Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/geometry_nodes.html) modifiers have a `node_group` attribute.

Geometry Nodes Trees can be accessed by name from the `bpy.data.node_groups` container.

```
import bpy

ao = bpy.context.active_object
modifier = next(m for m in ao.modifiers if m.type == 'NODES')
modifier.node_group = bpy.data.node_groups.get("My Other GN Tree")  # Case sensitive !!
```

Note if you have several GN modifiers on a single object, you'll need to know the name of the specific modifier you want to change. Replace line 2 with :

```
modifier = ao.modifiers.get("My Modifier Name")  # Case sensitive !!
```

Comment: Thank you!! works flawless :)

Comment: @blender_n00b If so, consider to accept the answer. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers