# Change the linked node on a node group using Python

Tags: python, materials, shader-nodes

I'm trying to figure out how to change the linked node in a node group on a material via python

```
bpy.data.node_groups['Group_Shadow']
```

[image]

I'd like to do the equivalent of picking a new link via here -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda similar to my [other answer there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238822/86891).

It's not that trivial because some nodes change their displayed name depending on what they are representing. Group nodes are used to modify node groups but a node group is an actual standalone node tree.

So the green node you are seeing is not actually the node group it represents, but a virtual link to it. You can enter a new interface to modify the sub-node tree it is linked to, by using <kbd>TAB</kbd> or clicking on the icon on its top right corner, but they are two different entities.

That being said, you'll need to know your group node's unique identifying name, which is different from its displayed name, which is the sub-node-tree's name.

[image]

```
import bpy

ao = bpy.context.active_object
m = ao.active_material
nodes = m.node_tree.nodes  # Get material nodes
gn = nodes.get("Group")  # Get the group node (Name is case-sensitive)
gn.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get("NodeGroup")  # Change the group node's node tree
```

Comment: That's awesome, many thanks. I had been circling around querying the _node_tree_, thinking there would be a list on some property. The notion of _get_ rather than _set_ here would have taken me an age to figure out, if at all. Cheers.

Comment: Well you can also do `bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup"]` but using `get` prevents throwing a `KeyError` exception if the name can't be found. Instead it simply sets the group node's node tree to `None`